# Search for array value inside JSON column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When there is a single value, `whereJsonContains` does the job. But in this case, I have an array which is as a result of saving to JSON column being converted into string. Here is the example:

```
[
   {
      "key":"cUyV6kW3noxxW85G",
      "value":"value-1",
   },
   {
      "key":"R8dHf4vWBS8M4W5G",
      "value":"value-2",
      "multidimensional_array":{
         "table":[
            {
               "attributes":{
                  "array":"[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\",\"6\",\"7\",\"8\",\"9\",\"10\"]"
               }
            }
         ],
      }
   },
   {
      "key":"cUyV6kW3noxxW85G",
      "value":"value-3",
   },
]
```

I want to get those elements which contain specific value inside array. Here is my try, but it's not working, no results are being returned:

```
ExampleTable::whereJsonContains('example_column', ['multidimensional_array' => ['table' => ['attributes' => ['array' => $specific_value]]]])->get();
```

Is it even possible to do it this way, or do I need to get every single result which has `multidimensional_array` and `json_decode()` `array` so I can iterate over it to look for what I need?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#json-where-clauses

You should use the `whereJsonContains` a bit different;

```
ExampleTable::whereJsonContains('multidimensional_array->table->attributes->array', $specific_value)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually you can use it both ways, but that's not what causing this problem I think. The problem is that `array` is represented as a string and instead of comparing `$specified_value` with `array` elements, whole `array` is seen as single element and therefore `false` is always being returned

Comment: Ah I see, hm I think this will be difficult then.. You should convert the original array to json and store it in the database, this will be a lot easier to fetch, search but also to convert back to array again. Is that possible (even this solution is not what you asked for)